# Ul LI Binding with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJs . I want repeated UL and each UL having two LI . 
In Model, I have array of Customer Object.

```
Customers =[{Customer:1},{Customer:2},{Customer:3},{Customer:4},{Customer:5}];
```

In View I want like below,

```
<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul>
<ul><li>3</li><li>4</li></ul>
<ul><li>5</li></ul>
```

Comment: Can you alter your JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/F45Db/

```
    <ul ng-repeat="c in dummy track by $index" ng-class="{last: $last}">
        <li ng-repeat="cust in Customers"
            ng-if="$index >= $parent.$index*2 && $index < $parent.$index*2 + 2">
             {{cust.Customer}}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

js:

```
function Controller($scope){
    $scope.Customers = [{Customer:1},{Customer:2},{Customer:3},{Customer:4},{Customer:5}];
    $scope.$watchCollection('Customers', function(){
        if($scope.Customers.length){
            $scope.dummy = new Array(Math.ceil($scope.Customers.length/2));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I want Output exactly same . But I think ,I  have to learn more to understand Angular and code like "c in dummy track by $index"

Comment: `dummy` is just a dummy array of the desired length (so ng-repeat can loop through it) but with every element undefined. And therfore you have to add `track by $index` because all items are undefined and otherwise you would get a "duplicates" error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting a single unordered list with li items you can see [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/UxSA1fiK69DMb3CvMQ4h?p=preview) plunkr with your example.  How will you decide when to start the second ul?  You are also not displaying the li for 5 at all.

html:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="person in customers">
    {{person.Customer}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

The javascript could look like this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.customers =[{Customer:1},{Customer:2},{Customer:3},{Customer:4},{Customer:5}];
});
```

Comment: Actually I want to display like this<ul ><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul>
<ul><li>3</li><li>4</li></ul><ul class='last'><li>5</li></ul>